# How to compare file sizes for two different dates in Linux by using Python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, filesize, file-comparison

I'm a newbie in python and I will backup my server data everyday.
I use shell script to check my backup dates, but when the Web Host become more and more using shell script need to change a lot.
So, I want to use python to check my backup file.

My Env is:

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Python Version: 3.4.3

My directories and files structure are like:

```
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Config/crontab_backup_20171105.txt
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Config/mysql_config_backup_20170724.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Web/2017/11/SPT_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Config/nginx_config_backup_20171030.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/CN/LHD-1/Web/2017/11/LHD_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/CN/LHD-1/Config/crontab_backup_20171105.txt
/mnt/disk2/CN/LHD-1/Config/mysql_config_backup_20170724.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/CN/TTY_1/Web/2017/11/TTY_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz
/mnt/disk2/CN/TTY_1/Config/nginx_config_backup_20171030.tar.gz
```

Because of my backup file have datetime on it, so my shell script will use today's file size to minus yesterday's file size.
If equal 0 that means backup file are not change, if not 0 it will send alert mail to notify me.

(But if the file size difference is not big, it does not matter. I only need to notice those file size difference of more than **1GB**. So, these is why I don't use **md5** or **filecmp** to comparison)

Now I want to make the same function program by using python, but I stuck on calculate file sizes for two different dates.

This is my code:

```
## Import Module
import sys
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Global Variables
jpWebList = ["/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web", "/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Web"]
jpConfigList = ["/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Conig", "/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Config"]

## Function Program
#-- Get file name's time and calculate yesterday.
def findYtdFile(filePath):
    YtdData = ""
    fsize = 0
    now = datetime.now()
    aDay = timedelta(days=-1)
    yDay = now + aDay
    yDay = yDay.strftime("%Y%m%d") # formatted the byDay value into 20170820.
    # print(yDay) # Check yDay's value.
    # print(filePath)
    if re.search(yDay, filePath) is not None:
        # print(filePath)
        YtdData = filePath
        # print(YtdData) # Check what kinds of file we got.
        fsize = os.path.getsize(YtdData)
        print(YtdData, "--file size is", fsize)

    return fsize

#-- Get file name's time and calculate the day before yesterday
def findDbyFile(filePath):
    DbyData = ""
    fsize = 0
    now = datetime.now()
    aDay = timedelta(days=-2)
    byDay = now + aDay
    byDay = byDay.strftime("%Y%m%d") # formatted the byDay value into 20170820
    # print(byDay) # Check byDay's value.
    if re.search(byDay, filePath) is not None:
        DbyData = filePath
        fsize = os.path.getsize(DbyData)
        print(DbyData, "--file size is", fsize)

    return fsize

#--Main, Get tar.gz and txt file list.
for tmpList in jpWebList:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tmpList): # recursive to get directories and files list.
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith((".tar.gz", ".txt")):
                filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                ytdFileSize = findYtdFile(filePath)
                dbyFileSize = findDbyFile(filePath)
                a = ytdFileSize - dbyFileSize
                print(a)
```

and the terminal shows:

```
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_backend_20171106_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 76021633
76021633
0
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_backend_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 76012434
-76012434
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_Test_backend_20171106_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 62391961
62391961
0
0
0
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_Test_front_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 82379384
-82379384
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_Test_front_20171106_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 82379384
82379384
0
0
0
0
0
/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web/2017/11/TFP_Test_backend_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz --file size is 62389231
-62389231
```

The answer suppose to like "TFP_Test_front_20171106_htdocs.tar.gz(82379384)" minus "TFP_Test_backend_20171105_htdocs.tar.gz(62389231)" equal to 19990153.

I have been try **glob**, **re.findall**, **os.listdir** but still don't work fine.
Is there anything I did not notice? or something I can refer to?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what is wrong in your code, but I've changed your code and tried to simplify it:

```
import sys, os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

jpWebList = ["/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Web", "/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Web"]
jpConfigList = ["/mnt/disk2/JP/TFP-1/Conig", "/mnt/disk2/JP/SPT_1/Config"]

def get_date(d):
    aDay = timedelta(days=d)
    byDay = datetime.now() + aDay
    return byDay.strftime("%Y%m%d")

#main
today = get_date(0)
yesterday = get_date(-1)

for tmpList in jpWebList:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tmpList): 
        todays_files = [file for file in files if today in file and file.endswith((".tar.gz", ".txt"))]
        yesterdays_files = [file for file in files if yesterday in file and file.endswith((".tar.gz", ".txt"))]     
        for todays_file in todays_files:
            yesterdays_file = todays_file.replace(today, yesterday)
            if yesterdays_file in yesterdays_files:
                todays_path = os.path.join(root, todays_file)
                yesterdays_path = os.path.join(root, yesterdays_file)
                size_difference = os.path.getsize(todays_path) - os.path.getsize(yesterdays_path)
                print(size_difference)
```

I can't check it completely without folders and files that you have, but I tried with 2 files, and it works fine. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I refer to your code and this really inspired me a lot.
I did not think I could use two for loop to make it.
Thanks again.